# Как правильно: В лоджии или НА лоджии?

Tags: согласование, падежи, предлоги

*Вернувшись в гостиницу, они уселись **в лоджии** и принялись составлять план действий.*
[**А.Маринина, Личные мотивы**](http://knijky.ru/books/lichnye-motivy?page=68)

*После ужина они уселись **на** крохотной **лоджии** и, по привычке, под музыку рисовали каждая свой орнамент.*
[**Фаня Шифман, Второй лабиринт**](https://ruslib.net/read/b/17888/p/63)

Где? - **в** лоджии или **на** лоджии. Куда? - **в** лоджию или **на** лоджию.
Поясните, пожалуйста, КАК правильно?

Answer (score 2):

И то, и другое верно, когда употребляется с пониманием какого характера лоджия. Лоджия может быть мелкой, являющейся по сути частью общего балкона-галереи (ваш прим.: *на крохотной лоджии*), а также — глубокой, более уединённой, практически — комнатой, но вовне открытой (*в лоджии*, ср.: *в ложе*).

В последние два десятилетия неуправляемый процесс остекления и включения лоджий в состав отапливаемых площадей понятие превратилось в фантом. Именно о такой «лоджии» пишет А. Маринина, — той, от которой остался звук и выступающие простенки. «В лоджии» — в её случае означает — в том месте теперешней комнаты, где была лоджия.

Comment: А как же быть, если невозможно понять: КАКОГО ВИДА и РАЗМЕРА лоджия? Например: "Если гардеробная будет находиться В лоджии, совмещенной со спальней, — это еще удобнее..." ; "Как утеплить пол НА лоджии своими руками?"

Comment: То, что будет или стало лоджией после «совмещения со спальней» или после утепления пола, лоджией являться не будет. У совмещённого помещения всегда одно название, и пол лоджии не утепляют, это непозволительное дело — обогревать улицу.

Comment: Зачем же Вы передергиваете? Мы ведь здесь не СНиПы и технические регламенты обсуждаем.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я не могу во всем согласиться с **shampar**, но он явно не на СНиП'ах аргументирует. Просто есть два значения у "лоджии" (см. мой ответ), и это известно далеко не только составителям докуметов.

Comment: *А как же быть, если невозможно понять* - ну это уже не филологам вопрос. Посмотрите, на что больше похоже или спросите у того, кто видел. Ну или разберитесь в значениях, если проблема в этом.

Answer (score 2):

> Всего найдено: 1
>    Вопрос № 272486
>
> Как правильно "на лоджии" или "в лоджии"?
>
> Ответ справочной службы русского языка
>
> Выбор предлога зависит от значения слова "лоджия" (ср. 1 и 2, в 
>   последнем примере возможен предлог "на") и от предшествующего глагола.
>
> ЛОДЖИЯ, -и; ж. [итал. loggia]
>   1. Здание, помещение, у которого вместо наружной стены открытая  колоннада, решётка или парапет. Выставка устроена в лоджии.
>   2. Глубокая ниша в фасаде здания, используемая как балкон. Въехать в квартиру с лоджией. Застеклить лоджию. Поставить стол в лоджии.

(с) Справка грамотная.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B8

Все это очень хорошо, но нас-то интересует именно второе значение, когда оба предлога возможны. А вот когда какой, справка, увы, не конкретизирует. 
*Хотя у Марининой не ясно, какое из двух имеется в виду, но предположим, что второе (иначе все было бы слишком просто).*

Так вот, мне кажется, во втором случае просто колебания в норме. Ни то, ни другое не противоречит общим принципам использования предлогов в/на и их вариативности и частичной взаимозаменяемости.

За предлог "В" говорит то, что лоджия в отличие от балкона - относительно замкнутое пространство, а в таких случаях язык тяготеет именно к предлогу "В", хотя не абсолютно.

С другой стороны у лоджии, как и у балкона "системообразующая" поверхность все равно только одна - пол (стенки с перилами-оградой скорее дополнение).

В общем, к чему душа лежит, то и правильно. Примеры, думаю, тут избыточны, найдете на все случаи жизни. Лично я склоняюсь, что сидеть надо все-таки НА лоджии, а вот там белье сушить - в лоджии.

В отношении аналогии "в кухне" / "на кухне". Она есть, но весьма слабая. Там-то, в/на кухне, все обычно определяется различием значений. "В кухне" - это строго в комнате, максимум - в отдельном сооружении типа "летняя кухня". Как только акцент делается на функциональную составляющую "готовтить на кухне", но явственно проступает предпочтительность НА. Есть третий случай - "приготовить В полевой кухне" - но тут уже совсем другой смысл, кухня не как помещение или место, а как устройство. Вот если для лоджии обнаружится что-то подобное, то я с аналогией такой соглашусь.  А пока в большинстве случаев для меня НА как-то более привычно

В интернете есть несколько обсуждений, но какого-то единого и обоснованного мнения не вижу.
Вот просто для примера.
https://rusforus.ru/viewtopic.php?t=1077

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о "глубокой нише в фасаде здания, используемой как балкон, то, как мне кажется, **правильным вариантом является "на лоджии"**, потому что правильно "**на балконе"**. Именно такой вариант закрепился в речи.

Современный застекленный балкон и внешне мало отличается от лоджии, и лоджию часто называют балконом, но дело даже **не в различии конструкций**.

У лоджии и балкона **одинаковая функция**, именно поэтому лоджия просто "**заимствовала**" предложную форму балкона (на балконе, на лоджии).

**Таково свойство языка:** выделять главное содержание и не замечать мелкие детали.

Answer (score 0):

Думается, "характер лоджии" тут ни при чем. Как ни при чем, например, характер кухни: ведь мы говорим и "на кухне" и "в кухне". Как ни при чем и характер концерта сто лет назад и сейчас: раньше ходили "в концерт", сейчас — исключительно "на концерт". Вещи ни при чем, это просто язык, грамматика.